# Owl Carousel not initializing when including jQuery in HTML Head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, owl-carousel

It seems that owl carousel is not initializing if jQuery is included in the HTML head section (including in body is working fine). In detail: The div-container with class owl-carousel has still defined `display: none`. In correctly initialized owl containers the class `owl-loaded` is added to the container by JavaScript which causes to overwrite `display: none` with `display: block`. Furthermore all options loaded on document ready are ignored:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-carousel").owlCarousel({
        items: 4,
        itemsCustom: false,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 2],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 2],
        itemsTablet: [768, 2],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        singleItem: false,
        startDragging: true,
        autoPlay: 4000
    });
});
```

However, I need jQuery in the header for building some angular directives which use jQuery UI components. Is there a way to initialize owl anyway?

Versions I currently use:

- Owl Carousel v2.2.0
- jQuery v1.11.3

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: I'm sorry for not answering your suggestions quite a long time. I had no luck with using `noConflict` but as a workaround I delayed initializing owlCarousel which works for me - even if jQuery is included in the head-section:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#my-carousel").owlCarousel({...});
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Seems like the issue is with css specificity. Can you post the complete HTML?

Comment: You right, you should insert `jq` in footer with `owl.js` in `body` but in your case a solution is use two `jq` library with `noConflict`